# Почему scrollTo с начало срабатывает, а потом кидает обратно

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let y = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper div")[12].offsetTop;
  let x = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper div")[12].offsetLeft;
  window.scroll({
    top: y,
    left:x,
  })

};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
          perspective: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease; }
  body .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 44% 44% 44% 44% 44%;
    grid-template-rows: 44% 44% 44% 44% 44%;
    grid-gap: 0; }
    body .wrapper div.about {
      background-color: aliceblue; }
    body .wrapper div.bower {
      background-color: darkgreen; }
    body .wrapper div.contact {
      background-color: crimson; }
    body .wrapper div.extra {
      background-color: chocolate; }
    body .wrapper div.main {
      background-color: chartreuse; }
    body .wrapper div.portfolio {
      background-color: brown; }
    body .wrapper div.service {
      background-color: blueviolet; }
    body .wrapper div.stub1 {
      background-color: blue; }
    body .wrapper div.stub2 {
      background-color: aqua; }
    body .wrapper div iframe {
      overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">1
    </div>
    <div class="about">1
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio">1
    </div>
    <div class="main">1
    </div>
    <div class="about">1
    </div>
    <div class="service">1
    </div>
    <div class="bower">1
    </div>
    <div class="contact">1
    </div>
    <div class="service">1
    </div>
    <div class="bower">1
    </div>
    <div class="extra">1
    </div>
    <div class="stub1">1
    </div>
    <div class="stub2">1
    </div>
    <div class="extra">1
    </div>
    <div class="stub1">1
    </div>
    <div class="main">1
    </div>
    <div class="about">1
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio">1
    </div>
    <div class="main">1
    </div>
    <div class="about">1
    </div>
    <div class="service">1
    </div>
    <div class="bower">1
    </div>
    <div class="contact">1
    </div>
    <div class="service">1
    </div>
    <div class="bower">2
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

работает тут, и в FireFox, но в хром не работает

Comment: Проверьте что событие onload срабатывает позже, чем браузер скролит к тому месту, которое закэшировал с прошлого раза. Возможно события в нестандартном порядке идут или onload срабатывает раньше чем нужно.

Comment: функция и так вызывается после window.onload